# Angular2 Component joining multiple input components

Tags: html, typescript, angular, angular2-ngmodel

Consider the following scenario.  I want to use three `NameInputComponent`, which each wrap a text input, to construct a `FullNamesComponent`:

- Two `NameInputComponent`s, for a pair of individual first names (`firstName1` & `firstName2`)
- One `NameInputComponent`, for a shared last name (`sharedLastName`)

The FullNamesComponent should expose two full names:

- `fullName1 = firstName1 + ' ' + sharedLastName`
- `fullName2 = firstName2 + ' ' + sharedLastName`

What would be the proper way to link these components together?  I have tried using `ngModel`, which allows me to bind the value of the input to a variable in the `NameInputComponent`, but I'm at a loss for how to keep building up so I can do something with these values in a parent component.  From what I understand, I need to use an `EventEmitter` to make the value consumable from a parent, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I should note this isn't being used as a form to be submitted.  I'm looking to bind to the outputs and use them for other portions of the page, as well as be able to change the content of the inputs programmatically/via bindings to other sections of the page.

Here is what I have so far:

#### name-input.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'name-input',
  template: `
    <h2>{{inputValue}}</h2>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue">
  `
})
export class NameInputComponent {
  inputValue: string; // <= How do I detect changes to this?
}
```

#### full-names.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'full-names',
  template: `
    {{fullName1}} &amp; {{fullName2}}
    <name-input #firstName1></name-input>
    <name-input #firstName2></name-input>
    <name-input #sharedLastName></name-input>
  `,
  directives: [
    NameInputComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    NameInputComponent
  ]
})
export class FullNamesComponent {
  fullName1: string; // No idea how to link these
  fullName2: string; // to values in components above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider something like this.

Assume you want to have **FullNamesComponent** to listen to the event (change) on the **NameInputComponent**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'name-input',
  template: `
    <h2>{{inputValue}}</h2>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" ()="nameChanged.emit($event.target.value)">
  `,
  outputs: ['nameChanged']
})
export class NameInputComponent {
  inputValue: string; // <= How do I detect changes to this?
  nameChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

then **FullNamesComponent** would be similar to

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'full-names',
  template: `
    {{fullName1}} &amp; {{fullName2}}
    <name-input #firstName1 (nameChanged)="firstName1Changed($event)"></name-input>
    <name-input #firstName2 (nameChanged)="firstName2Changed($event)"></name-input>
    <name-input #sharedLastName (nameChanged)="sharedLastNameChanged($event)"></name-input>
  `,
  directives: [
    NameInputComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    NameInputComponent
  ]
})
export class FullNamesComponent {
  firstName1: string; 
  firstName2: string; 
  sharedLastName: string;

  firstName1Changed(inName: string) {
     this.fullName1 = inName;
     // do something
  }
  firstName2Changed(inName: string) {
     this.fullName2 = inName;
     // do something
  }
  sharedLastNameChanged(inName: string) {
     this.sharedLastName = inName;
     // do something
  }
}
```

last, I do not think you need to specify `providers: [NameInputComponent]` in **FullNamesComponent** since NameInputComponent is a Directive you use in the template of FullNamesComponent and is not as part of the DependencyInjection mechanism.

I hope I have understood your point and that this helps